# Convert simple Dockerfile to docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple `Dockerfile` for `php:7.2-fpm` that is being referenced by my `docker-compose.yml` configuration. I want to get rid of the `Dockerfile` which is located at `php/Dockerfile` and integrate the commands to my `docker-compose-yml` file.

Here is my `php/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml` which brings up php-fpm, nginx, letencrypt certbot, mysql, and phpmyadmin:

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        container_name: dev_php
        build:
            context: ./php
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - ./website:/website
            - ./php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

    nginx:
        container_name: dev_nginx
        image: nginx:1.13.8
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./website:/website
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
        command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

    certbot:
        container_name: dev_certbot
        image: certbot/certbot
        volumes:
            - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

    mysql:
        container_name: dev_mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: dev_pma
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - mysql
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8183:80
```

Since my `php/Dockerfile` is relatively simple, I thought I could do something like this:

```
php:
    container_name: dev_php
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes:
        - ./website:/website
        - ./php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    command: bash -c "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"
```

But this does not work. When I bring my project up using `docker-compose up` I can see `dev_php` (the name of the PHP container) perform a bunch of tasks that I do not ordinarily see, it then proceeds to install `mysqli` but then quits immediately after with `exit code 0`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original Dockerfile does much more than just installing the `mysqli` extension.

It has the entrypoint as shown in the source code [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L219)

It also has the command as shown [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L263)

These entrypoint and command are what will start the container and keep it running

---

Now back to your modification:

> I can see dev_php (the name of the PHP container) perform a bunch of tasks that I do not ordinarily see

This is the output of `docker-php-ext-install mysqli`. You did not see it before is because it was done when building the docker image.

> quits immediately after with exit code 0

This is expected because the command has finished processing and there is nothing else for it to do.

In order to keep the container running, you will have to manually add in the original entrypoint and command. Something like this:

```
php:
    container_name: dev_php
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes:
        - ./website:/website
        - ./php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    entrypoint:
        - bash
        - -c
    command:
        - |
          docker-php-ext-install mysqli; \
          docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

I have not tested to confirm that the syntax is 100% correct but you should get the idea. The important bit is `docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm`

---

My recommendation is to just stick to using Dockerfile in this case.

1. A good side effect is that Docker will cache the build layers so you do not need to wait for the installing process of `mysqli` every time you want to start the containers.
2. You may consider [enabling](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/391#issuecomment-346590029) the extension too

Comment: The biggest reason I don't want to continue to use the Dockerfile is when I check the system for which packages I use via `docker image ls` then `php`is not display since it is only referenced from the `Dockerfile`. Nothing big, but nice to know what all I use.

Comment: You know that you can use `image` with `build` flag? In that case, docker will build the image and save the image name as the value of the the `image` flag. You can refer to the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build